# What is in the future for REVU

Tags: application-development, development, motu

Now that there is the Post Release Apps Process in place and there is a big push to get new software into Ubuntu, what are the future plans for REVU?

Will there be an application review board for [REVU](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MOTU/Packages/REVU) or will it remain what it is now, hit and miss at best.

Answer (score 3):

There are no plans to change REVU.  It is still meant to be the way to get an application into the repos and have it stay there from release to release.  The ARB is only for applications that are going in for a single already-stable release.

REVU would be less hit-or-miss if the submissions were better though :-/  Many of the packages sit there with comments saying "you need to fix foo" for months and no new uploads with those fixes happen.

Comment: Maco, thanks for the response, I agree that submissions could be better, however why expend all this developer time on apps that will only be in one release, wouldn't developer time be better spent by reviewing packages that will be part of the archive long term?  Not to mention submissions to the ARB may not be any better quality than what is on REVU

Comment: Oh I agree that the ARB is a stupid idea.  Some people seem to think there is a need for a way to submit applications to stable releases without the *oh so onerous* (/sarcasm) backports process.  On the other hand, at least the junk people don't want to maintain will go away after one release.  Most of what gets submitted to REVU stops being maintained before it even passes the REVU process...what does get through is often abandoned shortly thereafter adding more to the pile of crap MOTU have to take care of. At least Debian packages have specific maintainers and can be orphaned/removed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any immediate plans for technical changes in REVU and the new package submission process, but one significant policy change for new packages in recent times is that the primarily recommended way to get a new package into Ubuntu if you want to be the person who is responsible for it (as opposed to team maintenance) is now to [do it through Debian](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuDevelopment/NewPackages#NEW%20packages%20through%20Debian).